# Things that can happen to a differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We have a list of things that can happen to a differential equation $y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), y(t_0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous.

That is given by

(i) $ b = \infty$

(ii) $\lim \sup \limits_{t \rightarrow b} ||y _{\max(t)}||=\infty$

(iii) $ \lim \inf \limits_{t \rightarrow b} \text{dist}((t,y_{max(t)}),\partial G)=0 $

where $ y_{max}$ is the maximal solution of the IVP
Now I have troubles to interpret the meaning of (iii). Can someone give me a hint, how to interpret this?

Comment: You don't say what $b$ is.  I suspect you mean that $(a, b)$ is the maximal open interval containing $t_0$ on which the solution exists.

Comment: yes you are correct, sorry that I forgot that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $f$ is only defined on $G$.  If the solution left $G$, the differential equation would cease to be defined. (iii) is saying that as $t$ approaches $b$, you come close (at least some of the time) to the boundary of $G$.
For example, perhaps you don't need the "inf": $(t,y(t))$ actually approaches a point on the boundary of $\delta G$, and then there is no differential equation to solve.  In more pathological cases, $y(t)$ can fluctuate wildly near the boundary of $G$, so that $\lim_{t \to b-} y(t)$ doesn't exist.